# How to decode events help on substrate using polkadot.js?

Tags: polkadot-js, rust

I have a base smart contract in `rust` with package manager `cargo`. In that smart contract I have some events which I'm emitting while function calling. For listing that events I have a service in `java script` but I'm not sure how to decode that event that trigger by contract while there is a transaction happened in a blockchain using that smartcontract. I have a link from where I can decode that `https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/f701c398c349159d5afd7344ea38c1d52e4aab56/packages/api-contract/src/Abi/index.ts#L111` but I have implement that but not able to decode the events. I'm pasting my contract and service here let me know if you got something or suggest something.

**Contract**

```
#![cfg_attr(not(feature = "std"), no_std)]

use ink_lang as ink;

#[ink::contract]
mod test {

    /// Defines the storage of your contract.
    /// Add new fields to the below struct in order
    /// to add new static storage fields to your contract.
    #[ink(storage)]
    pub struct Test {
        /// Stores a single `bool` value on the storage.
        value: bool,
    }

    /// Event emitted when a token transfer occurs.
    #[ink(event)]
    pub struct Transfer {
        #[ink(topic)]
        from: Option<AccountId>,
        #[ink(topic)]
        to: Option<AccountId>,
        value: Balance,
    }

    impl Test {
        /// Constructor that initializes the `bool` value to the given `init_value`.
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn new(init_value: bool) -> Self {
            Self { value: init_value }
        }

        /// Constructor that initializes the `bool` value to `false`.
        ///
        /// Constructors can delegate to other constructors.
        #[ink(constructor)]
        pub fn default() -> Self {
            Self::new(Default::default())
        }

        /// A message that can be called on instantiated contracts.
        /// This one flips the value of the stored `bool` from `true`
        /// to `false` and vice versa.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn flip(&mut self) {
            self.value = !self.value;
            Self::env().emit_event(Transfer {
                from: None,
                to: None,
                value: 10000,
            });
        }

        /// Simply returns the current value of our `bool`.
        #[ink(message)]
        pub fn get(&self) {
            Self::env().emit_event(Transfer {
                from: None,
                to: None,
                value: 10000,
            });
        }
    }

    /// Unit tests in Rust are normally defined within such a `#[cfg(test)]`
    /// module and test functions are marked with a `#[test]` attribute.
    /// The below code is technically just normal Rust code.
    #[cfg(test)]
    mod tests {
        /// Imports all the definitions from the outer scope so we can use them here.
        use super::*;

        /// Imports `ink_lang` so we can use `#[ink::test]`.
        use ink_lang as ink;

        /// We test if the default constructor does its job.
        #[ink::test]
        fn default_works() {
            let test = Test::default();
            assert_eq!(test.get(), false);
        }

        /// We test a simple use case of our contract.
        #[ink::test]
        fn it_works() {
            let mut test = Test::new(false);
            assert_eq!(test.get(), false);
            test.flip();
            assert_eq!(test.get(), true);
        }
    }
}
```

**Service.js**

```
const { ApiPromise, WsProvider } = require('@polkadot/api')
const { ContractPromise, Abi } = require('@polkadot/api-contract')
const {
  assert,
  assertReturn,
  compactAddLength,
  compactStripLength,
  isNumber,
  isObject,
  isString,
  logger,
  stringCamelCase,
  stringify,
  u8aConcat,
  u8aToHex,
} = require('@polkadot/util')

// Import the test keyring (already has dev keys for Alice, Bob, Charlie, Eve & Ferdie)
const { Keyring } = require('@polkadot/keyring')

const bridgePerr = require('./flipper/examples/test/target/ink/metadata.json')

const Contract_Address_Peer = '5FfwrjcXmWsCZCtzRJPwtPBS3AEnPKJy9c2yEi17mFa5hhS3'

// Acc :- 30 may 11:33
const Peer_Private_key =
  '0xb0969cc635d807e6d6bfcb05cad88758c64df2da338050ce2103815653d05606'

const PeerProvider = new WsProvider('ws://127.0.0.1:9944')

// const self = '5GrwvaEF5zXb26Fz9rcQpDWS57CtERHpNehXCPcNoHGKutQY'
const to = '5Gue2tLHMZrfaeX6gDNs8EAPm64mpAnHsWWw5TWhGsb3Fkxo'
const AMOUNT = 1000000000000

async function main() {
  const api = await ApiPromise.create({ PeerProvider })

  //ed25519 edwards
  const keyring = new Keyring({ type: 'ed25519' })

  const PeerBridge = new ContractPromise(api, bridgePerr, Contract_Address_Peer)
  // the address we are going to query

  // Find the actual keypair in the keyring
  // const alicePair = keyring.getPair(target)
  const userPair = keyring.addFromUri(Peer_Private_key)

  console.log('Sending', AMOUNT, 'from', userPair.address, 'to', to)

  PeerBridge.tx
    .get({
      value: 0,
      gasLimit: -1,
    })
    .signAndSend(userPair, ({ events = [], status }) => {
      console.log('Transaction status:', status.type)

      if (status.isInBlock) {
        console.log('Included at block hash', status.asInBlock.toHex())
        console.log('Events:')

        events.forEach(({ event: { data, method, section }, phase }) => {
          console.log(
            '\t',
            phase.toString(),
            `: ${section}.${method}`,
            data.toString(),
          )
        })
      } else if (status.isFinalized) {
        console.log('Finalized block hash', status.asFinalized.toHex())

        process.exit(0)
      }
    })
}

main()
```

**logs**

```
    Transaction status: Ready
    Transaction status: InBlock
    Included at block hash 0x20da51303e5e1518e90844be6823f85e51666cc27ee652960d25b65902a97e59
    Events:
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : balances.Withdraw ["5Cht6EkuACEXLrF8XBywqZPDCL9AEgSQXS4MB6dwgZAeqCVc",2828033563974]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : contracts.ContractEmitted ["5DskQxeMsqqueJzauUsbh8xYiiDKR4x7e5Kz29pkCJ1EKmwZ","0x00000010270000000000000000000000000000"]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : balances.Deposit ["5Cht6EkuACEXLrF8XBywqZPDCL9AEgSQXS4MB6dwgZAeqCVc",1268853627292]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : balances.Deposit ["5EYCAe5ijiYfyeZ2JJCGq56LmPyNRAKzpG4QkoQkkQNB5e6Z",1247343949345]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : treasury.Deposit [1247343949345]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : balances.Deposit ["5GNJqTPyNqANBkUVMN1LPPrxXnFouWXoe2wNSmmEoLctxiZY",311835987337]
             {"applyExtrinsic":1} : system.ExtrinsicSuccess [{"weight":9072880260,"class":"Normal","paysFee":"Yes"}]
    Transaction status: Finalized
    Finalized 

block hash 0x20da51303e5e1518e90844be6823f85e51666cc27ee652960d25b65902a97e59
```

Anyone please suggest something or help me in this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You want to decode the data from [ContractEmitted](https://polkadot.js.org/docs/substrate/events#contractemittedaccountid32-bytes). So you are half-way there in known that you can pass the `Bytes` to the [decodeEvent](https://github.com/polkadot-js/api/blob/master/packages/api-contract/src/Abi/index.ts#L111) on the API.

In mostly pseudo-code, you would need to adjust your event check loop -

```js
events.forEach(({ event, phase }) => {
  if (api.events.contracts.ContractEmitted.is(event)) {
    // we are dealing with a contract event
    const [account_id, contract_evt] = event.data

    // find out ABI based on the accountId for the contract
    // here we assume we have stored ABIs for our known addresses
    const abi = abis[account_id.toString()]

    // decode
    const decoded = abi.decodeEvent(contract_evt)

    // display results, etc.
    ...
  } else {
    // normal/other event logic
  }
})
```