# Unable to decode contract event: Unable to find event

Tags: polkadot-js, ink, wasm

Ive got this error on my console although transaction was succeeded.

what causes this error..?

[image]

Comment: Can you share the code of the SC, looks there is something wrong with the event

Comment: [Decode events on smart contract](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/a/2948/2844)

Comment: @AlexBean https://github.com/Interoperable-swap/frontend/tree/develop/interface
provably the issue is happening at component/Main.js

Comment: How can I replicate it? Which operation are you trying to do?

Answer (score 1):

You would have to post the code snippet of how you are trying to do the decoding, but I have a guess:

The contract metadata is used for decoding events, the fact that you're trying to decode but can't points to a mismatch in metadata.

So likely your frontend uses the wrong contract metadata.