# connect Polkadot{js} API correctly

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, api

`Your API has not been initialized correctly and is not connected to a chain`

the API is successfully connected and return value, but all `ContractPromise` cause this error.

Anyone know how to solve this?
[image: error screenshot]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following [your code](https://github.com/Interoperable-swap/frontend/tree/develop/interface) you shared with me in this [question](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/5841/unable-to-decode-contract-event-unable-to-find-event) I can see there is an issue with the initialisation of the api variable you are using.

In the useEffect() of your Main.js file you are using the variable api.

```
const getToken1Contract = new ContractPromise(api, PSP22_ABI, address0)
```

You initialize it in the TransactionContext.js file in the method connectWallet()

```
const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider })
setapi(api)
```

But the issue here is that when app is rendering is trying to access this api variable before the connectWallet() is executed.

You can do that in the setup in Main.js:

```
 const provider = new WsProvider(WS_PROVIDER)
 const api = await ApiPromise.create({ provider })
 setapi(api)
```

Or check that the api variable is initialised it before used and show a message to connect the wallet.

Comment: I realized why it's happened. And I could fix them! Thanks your help! I changed it to execute after checking api is available like this  `if (api) {setup()}`